# How to deal with a convex constraint

Tags: convex-optimization, constraints, constraint-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

I want to deal with a convex constraint
\begin{align}
F(P)=P^{H}AP_{0}+P_{0}^{H}AP-P_{0}^{H}AP_{0}\succeq 0
\end{align}
where $(\cdot)^{H}$ represents Hermitian transpose, $A$ is a positive definite matrix, $P_{0}$ is a given square matrix and $P$ is also a square matrix. Since this constraint can be represented alternatively as
\begin{align}
v^{H}(P^{H}AP_{0}+P_{0}^{H}AP-P_{0}^{H}AP_{0})v \geq 0,\quad \forall v\in C^{n}
\end{align}
which is a affine function of $P$, we know that this is a convex constraint. However, I'm not sure how to deal with this constraint in a convex optimization problem. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Define "deal with". What are you trying to do? What is the full model you're trying to solve? This is just a linear matrix inequality, and there is a wealth of information on the internet about how to solve problems involving LMIs.